# openSUSE - Remove all packages from a repository

Tags: opensuse, cinnamon, zypper

I've installed **cinnamon** in my *openSUSE* to try it, but I didn't liked and removed **cinnamon** and **cinnamon-session**, but I noticed that there were still a lot of packages from this repository installed.

```
# zypper search --installed-only --repo Cinnamon
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                                 | Summary                  | Type   
--+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------
i | cinnamon-control-center              | The Control Center for-> | package
i | cinnamon-control-center-lang         | Languages for package -> | package
i | cinnamon-desktop-lang                | Languages for package -> | package
i | cinnamon-screensaver                 | Cinnamon screensaver a-> | package
i | cinnamon-settings-daemon             | The settings Daemon fo-> | package
i | cinnamon-settings-daemon-lang        | Languages for package -> | package
i | cinnamon-themes                      | Default Cinnamon Themes  | package
i | cinnamon-translations                | Translations for the C-> | package
i | cjs                                  | Javascript module used-> | package
i | gtk3-theme-vivagreen                 | openSUSE Cinnamon defa-> | package
i | libcinnamon-control-center1          | Shared libraries for C-> | package
i | libcinnamon-desktop4                 | Libcinnamon-desktop API  | package
i | libcinnamon-menu-3-0                 | A menu system for the -> | package
i | libcjs0                              | Shared Libraries for C-> | package
i | libmuffin0                           | Muffin shared libraries  | package
i | libnemo-extension1                   | Nemo extension shared -> | package
i | nemo                                 | File browser for Cinna-> | package
i | nemo-compare                         | Context Menu compariso-> | package
i | nemo-dropbox                         | DropBox support for th-> | package
i | nemo-emblems                         | Change a folder or fil-> | package
i | nemo-fileroller                      | Fileroller support for-> | package
i | nemo-gtkhash                         | Nemo extension for com-> | package
i | nemo-image-converter                 | Nemo extension to mass-> | package
i | nemo-media-columns                   | Nemo Media Columns       | package
i | nemo-pastebin                        | Pastebin extension for-> | package
i | nemo-preview                         | A quick previewer for -> | package
i | nemo-python                          | Python bindings for th-> | package
i | nemo-rabbitvcs                       | RabbitVCS extension fo-> | package
i | nemo-repairer                        | Nemo extension for fil-> | package
i | nemo-seahorse                        | OpenPGP encryption/dec-> | package
i | nemo-share                           | Samba share extension -> | package
i | nemo-terminal                        | Nemo extension to enab-> | package
i | python-kaa-base                      | The Kaa Media Reposito-> | package
i | python-kaa-metadata                  | The Kaa Media Reposito-> | package
i | typelib-1_0-CinnamonDesktop-3_0      | Libcinnamon-desktop AP-> | package
i | typelib-1_0-CinnamonMenu-3_0         | Libcinnamon-menu API --> | package
i | typelib-1_0-CjsPrivate-1_0           | Cinnamon JS module -- -> | package
i | typelib-1_0-MetaMuffin-0_0           | Muffin Introspection b-> | package
i | typelib-1_0-Nemo-3_0                 | File Browser for Cinna-> | package
i | wallpaper-cinnamon-branding-openSUSE | openSUSE Cinnamon defa-> | package
```

If I run

```
# zypper rr Cinnamon
```

those packages will be uninstalled? How should I proceed?

Thanks!